# Change Dates in Craft CMS

Tags: datetime

I want to change the dates of entries before the dates I actually edited the entries, I am trying to look in the database and I can't figure out which dates need to be changed. I have entries in Craft CMS of past dates and was looking for a way to alter those dates. I know I can manually alter it in the template by simply leaving the `{{ post.postDate | date("d") }}` and `{{ post.postDate | date("M") }}` or the same with `entry.postDate` leave it like it is but is there a way in Craft to do it easier and leave the template like it is?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the `postDate` of any entry manually through the entry edit form. Click on the `Post Date` input field in the sidebar to the right, there you can set the post date to whatever date and time you wish.

[image: Screenshot of the entry edit page showing the post date input with the opened date picker]

Comment: Thanks, i found it later how srupid i am, common sense but sometimes I don’t think that way.